# zend framework get data from two tables

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework, frameworks

if I use

```
 $query = $this
        ->select()
        ->from(array('a' => 'aanvragen'))
        ->join(array('v' => 'verloven'),
                   'v.aanvraag_id = a.id' ,array())
        ->where('a.personeelslid_id = :personeelslid_id')
        ->where('v.type = 3')
        ->bind(array(
            'personeelslid_id' => $this->_personeelslid->id
        ))
    ;
    return $this->fetchAll($query, array('aanvragen','verloven'));
```

I get the correct `record(s)` but no data from table `verloven(v)` due to `array()`.

But if I remove the empty array like:

```
     $query = $this
        ->select()
        ->from(array('a' => 'aanvragen'))
        ->join(array('v' => 'verloven'),
                   'v.aanvraag_id = a.id' )
        ->where('a.personeelslid_id = :personeelslid_id')
        ->where('v.type = 3')
        ->bind(array(
            'personeelslid_id' => $this->_personeelslid->id
        ))
    ;
    return $this->fetchAll($query, array('aanvragen','verloven'));
```

I get an error:

> Select query cannot join with another table.

What to do to get data from both tables?

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are using zf 1+ , you can do following from your model,

```
 $sql=$this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('a' => 'aanvragen'),array('field1','field2'))               
            ->join(array('v' => 'verloven'),'v.aanvraag_id = a.id',array('field3'))  
            ->where('a.personeelslid_id = :personeelslid_id')
            ->where('v.type = 3')   
            ->group('fieldname')
            ->order('fieldname');          

        $resultSet = $this->fetchAll($sql);
        return $resultSet;
```

you need to set setIntgrityCheck to false to join select query..
hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you should almost **NEVER** set `setIntegrityCheck(false)` if what you really need is something that is cross-table.

The right way to do this would be by using the `Zend_Db_Adapter`:

```
$query = $this
        ->getAdapter()
        ->select()
        ->from(array('a' => 'aanvragen'))
        ->join(array('v' => 'verloven'),
                   'v.aanvraag_id = a.id' ,array())
        ->where('a.personeelslid_id = :personeelslid_id')
        ->where('v.type = 3')
        ->bind(array(
            'personeelslid_id' => $this->_personeelslid->id
        ))
    ;
    return $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($query, array('aanvragen','verloven'));
```

The reasoning behind this is, that what you are using (asuming that your model extends from  `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`) is a **Table** context. Meaning, you are telling the framework, that you want to work with the specific table, and you do not care about other tables.

If you want to do a join, you should take a step up in the context ladder, and use the **Db** context, which can be obtained by using the `getAdapter()` method.